# Cannot connect to Android project to Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, database-connection

I am not able to connect my project to Firebase due to this error;

[image]

Below are my gradle files;

**App gradle**

[image]

**Project gradle**

[image]

I do not have gzip files in my project folder as some solutions suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible that you application Id is already in use. try to do it through firebase console. that will elaborate the error.

Comment: Thank you. It does seem like the application ID was already in use.